# C++ static local function vs global function

Tags: c++, static, global

What is the utility of having static functions in a file ?

How are they different from having global functions in a file ?

```
static int Square(int i)
{
   return i * i;
}
```

vs

```
int Square(int i)
{
   return i * i;
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> What is the utility of having static functions in a file?

You can use these functions to provide shared implementation logic to other functions within the same file. Various helper functions specific to a file are good candidates to be declared file-static.

> How are they different from having global functions in a file?

They are invisible to the linker, allowing other compilation units to define functions with the same signature. Using namespaces alleviates this problem to a large degree, but file-`static` functions predate namespaces, because they are a feature inherited from the C programming language.

Comment: It all became clear to me when I read that global functions are external by default, that is "void fun() {}" is identical to "extern void fun() {}"... still, if you don't put them in a header they can only be used within implementation file in which they are defined (below the point at which they are defined).

Comment: @Simon Knapp they can be used in different transition units by using a prototype.

Answer (score 28):

A `static` function simply means that the linker cannot export the function (i.e. make it visible to other [translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)).  It makes the function "private" to the current translation unit.  It is the same as wrapping the function in an anonymous namespace.

```
namespace {

    int Square(int i)
    {
       return i * i;
    } 

}
```

Generally, using an anonymous namespace is the preferred C++ way of achieving this, instead of using the `static` keyword.

Comment: Why is it preferred? It seems more verbose to me.

Comment: Yeah if you were in the middle of a 1000 line file it's easier to check whether a function is static than whether it's in a namespace, especially if you don't indent namespaces

Comment: Personally: because you're writing C++ code, not C, as it is a feature inherited from C. I tend to avoid features inherited from C. For example, I'd rather use `std::from_chars` rather than `atoi`, while the former being more verbose.

Comment: That's not really a reason @MarcDirven, just a preference

Comment: @Jarem Being good C++ programmer is to understand the idioms.

Answer (score 5):

Static functions are visible on the file where they were defined only.
You can't refer to them outside of that particular file.

[Read more here](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com.ar/2010/06/static-functions-in-c.html)

Answer (score 5):

In a word, linkage. `static` functions have internal linkage, that is, they aren't visible outside of their translation unit.